# Selenium - How do click on this span class

Tags: java, html, testing, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am not able to use xpath for this span class. I need to click on the link.

```
<span class="nav-selection">Ad Style</span>
```

I have been trying using this method:

```
WebElement heightClass = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[3]/a/span"));
```

The html code for the portion that I need to test.

```
<ul class="nav nav-side-menu" style="top: 0px;">
        <li class="shadow-layer"></li>
        <li>
            <a href="portal.do?portalCategory=analyst">
                <i class="icon-photon dashboard"></i>
                <span class="nav-selection">Dashboard</span>
                                </a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a href="javascript:;" class="sub-nav-container">
                <i class="icon-photon adcorner"></i>
                <span class="nav-selection">Ad Corner</span>
                <i class="icon-menu arrow"></i>                </a>
            <div class="sub-nav adCorner">
                <ul class="nav">

                    <li class="menu-add">
                        <a href="showstatusreports.do">Status Reports</a>
                    </li>


                    <li class="menu-add">
                        <a href="listinsertion.do">Insertion Order</a>                              
                    </li>
                    <li class="menu-add">
                        <a href="campaignWrapper.do?processpath=defaultPage&amp;camStatus=L">Campaigns</a>

                        <i class="icon-add" title="create new campaign" rel="createCampaign"></i>   

                    </li>






                    <li class="menu-add">
                        <a href="campaigncreatepage.do">Tags</a>                            
                    </li>







                        <li class="menu-add">
                        <a href="viewcreative.do">View Creative</a>
                        </li>


                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
```

Thanks for the help! Please let me know.

This is what i am writing in eclipse. please go through it and let me know. Thanks.

```
//class to run the test
public class AddNewCampaign extends TestLogin{

    WebDriver driver;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    AddNewCampaign addCamp = new AddNewCampaign();
    addCamp.LaunchParisUI();
    addCamp.loginCredentials();
    addCamp.addCampaign();


}

//method to add campagin

    public void addCampaign() { 

            WebElement heightclass = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[.='Ad Corner']/.."));

            WebElement linkCampaigns = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[3]/div/ul/li[3]/a"));

            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

            Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
            builder.moveToElement(heightclass).perform();
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(linkCampaigns));
            builder.moveToElement(linkCampaigns).click().perform();

        }

//class the launch the url

    public class LaunchParis{

        WebDriver driver;

        //Launch PairsUI    
        public void LaunchParisUI() {
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            //driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.get("https://xfpqa1uiadm1");
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            }
```

Comment: What is the problem you're having?  No result?  An exception?  If it is an exception, what exception is it?  As an aside, that xpath is fairly brittle.  If you edit your post and add more html, someone can likely suggest a better selector.

Comment: Exception in Thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Hi Richard, I added the html in my original post. Thanks

Comment: I don't see Ad Style in your html but I assume you are searching for Ad Corner. If so see my answer below

Comment: `NullPointerException` probably means that you are accessing an object that is `null`.  Could you post more of your code?

Comment: I don't like your linkCampaigns xpath. Are you directing to `<a href="campaignWrapper.do?processpath=defaultPage&amp;camStatus=L">Campaigns</a>` element? Are you trying to click on that element? why not a regular click?!

Comment: @Insane: Do you want to hover of the text **"Ad Corner"** first and then Click on **"Ad Style"** item under it ?

Answer (score 1):

From the very limited information you posted, you probably want:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='nav-selection']/parent::a"));
```

Find the `span` element with class `nav-selection`, and go to that element's parent anchor. Span is very seldom clickable, anchors is what you want to click on.

Comment: So you mean you do not have `driver` instantiated?!?!

Comment: That's possible, but I'd think the problem would have cropped up on `driver.get(url)`.

Answer (score 1):

The following can be another option. Before click you want to make sure you are letting element load. This is text based search. And, a good way to bypass the element having same classname or attribute value

```
WebElement heightClass = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[.='Ad Corner']/.."));
```

Comment: No Luck Saifur...still giving me the exception

Comment: I think  Richard is correct. You probably not instantiating the correctly

Comment: i have added the script above that i a trying to run. Thanks Guys!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have two instances of `driver`.  You have one instance in `AddNewCampaign`.  You have another instance of `driver` in `LaunchParis`.

So you're fine in `LaunchParis`, because you've created a local `driver`, which you then use to load the web page with the `driver.get()`.  After that, you return to the `main`, which still has an un-instantiated `driver`.

I'm not sure how exactly your code is structured.  You may be able to clear this problem simply by removing the `WebDriver driver` definition from `LaunchParis`, or you may need to pass `driver` to `LaunchParis`.

So, possibly something like this:

```
public class LaunchParis{

    WebDriver localDriver;

    //Launch PairsUI    
    public void LaunchParisUI(WebDriver driver) {
        localDriver = driver;
        localDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
        //localDriver = new ChromeDriver();
        localDriver.get("https://xfpqa1uiadm1");
        localDriver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
```

And you would call it like this:

```
addCamp.LaunchParisUI(driver);
```

I'm not entirely sure how that would work in Java, i.e. if assigning `localDriver = driver` would set the `AddNewCampaign` instance of `driver` as well.

Comment: I need to work out on how i am calling methods. I created a new project without inheritance, and xpath seems to work. Thanks for all of your help, Guys!